# how to enable menu bar when mouse is placed on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a menu which contains home,patient,reports etc. This menu should be present in each and every page and it should be present at the top right of each page. I know how to design this.Now i wanted to make it hidden and it should display only when mouse is placed at the top right side of a page.Please guys tell me how to do this.If you want the code for menu bar then here is this

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
    <head>
<style type="css/text">
body{
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title> Home</title>
        <meta name="author" content="jQuery Foundation - jquery.org">
        <meta name="description" content="jQuery: The Write Less, Do More, JavaScript Library">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
        <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.5.1" />
    </head>
    <body >
        <header>
            <section id="global-nav">
                <nav>
                    <div class="constrain">
                        <ul class="links">
                            <li><a href="template.html" target="content">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="createpatient.html" target="content">Patient</a></li>
                            <li><a href="template.html" target="content">Appointments</a></li>
                            <li><a href="template1.html" target="content">Reports</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.html" target="content">logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </section>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i have made a example for u i hope this helps the first example shows that whenu hover over the menu show but when u stop the hover on the box the menu will disapear

http://jsfiddle.net/nFwWG/

```
    $("#righttopbox").on('mouseenter',function(){
  $("#global-nav").show();
});
$("#righttopbox").on('mouseleave',function(){
  $("#global-nav").hide();
});
```

the second one show when u hover once the menu will stay

http://jsfiddle.net/nFwWG/1/

```
    $("#righttopbox").on('mouseenter',function(){
  $("#global-nav").show();
});
```

also dont forget to put jquery script on the header you can use this hosted by google by typing in google jquery google.

or you can download it at

www.jquery.com

hope this helps

Comment: see when i move over the block some menu appears on the left as per your code but when i move the mouse to click on the link then it disappears.can you please edit the code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `global-nav` is at top right

JS:

```
$("#global-nav").mouseenter(function(){

   $(".links", this).show();
}).mouseleave(function(){

   $(".links", this).hide();
});
```

CSS:

```
#global-nav .links {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: It may also be appropriate to give _.links_ absolute positioning  and a higher-than-the-rest z-index so that when it appears it covers other elements rather than pushing them down to make room.

Comment: it's recommned to use `ctx.find(selector)` rahter than `$(selector,ctx)` the latter is in the end transformed to the former but you are executing a series of unnecessary steps to get there

Answer (score 0):

If it is hidden and you want to make it appear when the mouse is at top right, then you probably have to use JavaScript with [mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/mousemove) event on the `body` or such. Then check the mouse co-ordinates and if it's in your pre-defined range (top-right) then show up the menu. As you can see `e.screenX` and `e.screenY` will give you the mouse coords relative to screen.